# Using DateAdd function to Calculate between 2 Dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out and flag if patient had an  x-ray  within one day when they first showed up in ER.

```
SELECT perosonID,
       xray_code,
       xray_date,
       admit_date,
       CASE
         WHEN xray_code IN ( '212', '345', '489' )
              AND admit_date BETWEEN DateAdd(day, 0, xray_date) 
                                 AND DateAdd(day, 1, xray_date) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS flag
FROM   my table
```

my results seem to be wrong and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around, i.e xray_date between ... etc ?

Comment: Show some dummy example data and desired results.

Comment: When you are working with time, you must be very precise in your requirements. When you say "within one day," do you mean "within the next 24 hours" or "by the end of the next day?" That can make quite a bit of difference. If admitted at 1 a.m. Tuesday morning, must the x-ray be made before 1 a.m. on Wednesday morning or before midnight on Wednesday? That's a 23 hour difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select perosonID
     , xray_code
     , xray_date
     , admit_date
     , Case when xray_code in (‘212’, 345’, ‘489’) 
             and  DATEDIFF(DAY, admit_date, xray_date) <= 1 
             then 1 
        else 0 end as flag
from my table
```

Comment: thanks Ali, i don't want to flag it when it is negative values because there are times like that..

Comment: Then do something like `DATEDIFF(DAY, admit_date, xray_date) IN (0,1)`